# Gradle wrapper gives error "Could not create plugin of type 'AppPlugin'"

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradlew

I've created a new project and changed nothing. When I try to execute a Gradle task with the Gradle Wrapper in that project, I get the following error:

> - What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'. Could not create plugin of type 'AppPlugin'.
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED

I'm using a Mac with OS X:
[image: Android Studio version info]

Project settings:

- Gradle version: 2.4
- Android Plugin Version: 1.3.0
- JDK: 1.7.0_71

The stacktrace:

```
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:54)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:152)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:40)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:26)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:34)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:493)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:80)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:31)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:142)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:113)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:81)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:50)
    at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:171)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:201)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:174)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:170)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:139)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:46)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:33)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:130)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.plugins.PluginInstantiationException: Could not create plugin of type 'AppPlugin'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginRegistry.loadPlugin(DefaultPluginRegistry.java:67)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginContainer.providePlugin(DefaultPluginContainer.java:103)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginContainer.addPluginInternal(DefaultPluginContainer.java:68)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginContainer.apply(DefaultPluginContainer.java:34)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.applyPlugin(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:116)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.access$200(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction$3.run(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:85)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.execute(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:129)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractPluginAware.apply(AbstractPluginAware.java:41)
    at org.gradle.api.Project$apply.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.ProjectScript.apply(ProjectScript.groovy:34)
    at org.gradle.api.Script$apply.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at build_5nelsiis404oagio54k2imkaac.run(/user/project/app/build.gradle:1)
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:52)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/StringGroovyMethods
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.<init>(BasePlugin.groovy:135)
    at com.android.build.gradle.AppPlugin.<init>(AppPlugin.groovy:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DependencyInjectingInstantiator.newInstance(DependencyInjectingInstantiator.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginRegistry.loadPlugin(DefaultPluginRegistry.java:65)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.StringGroovyMethods
    ... 50 more
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20811514/gradle-is-issuing-an-error-could-not-create-plugin-of-type-appplugin

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya so I need to downgrade the Android Plugin Version from 1.3.0 to 0.7.3? Android Studio gives a warning that version is not supported. Is Java 1.6 the problem? Then upgrading should also fix the problem?

Comment: ohhh..Please upgrade

Comment: I've updated Java to the latest version, but that didn't fix the problem. The JRE version in the Android Studio about screen didn't change from the update btw. And I've updated the question that I'm using a Mac

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24610194/android-studio-could-not-create-plugin-of-type-appplugin and change path

Comment: I've set gradle version to 1.12, but still same error. What do you mean by "change path"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89595/discussion-between-rule-and-intellij-amiya).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what caused this problem:
I was running the command with `gradlew cC` instead of `./gradleW cC`, using the `/Users/<username>/Library/Android/sdk/tools/templates/gradle/wrapper/gradlew` instead of the project's Gradle wrapper. Doh